# SVN copy from one to another URL with history

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, history

I'm trying to copy data from one to another server with history. I tried to copy from https:/api.blabla:89/svn to http:/mysnv.com/svn (different server, port..ect)
What I did:

> svnadmin dump https:/api.blabla:89/svn < someDump

and stored all history data to local drive. Now I sent that data to local repository

> svnadmin load "C:/testSvn" < someDump

Now I want to checkout that local repository to server. How to do that? What is next step after "load".

Comment: Did you already look at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnadmin ?

Comment: The "<" should be ">" for the dump or?

Comment: Yes, I did like you wrote and I have already looked at all documentation. But I seems like it does not suit for my problem.

Comment: As you are writing "Now I want to checkout that local repository to server. How to do that? ": You already tried a `svn co file:///path/to/testSvn local-workingcopy` on your server? Or what next step do you need/are you expecting?